What conditions does the principle of stationary action alone put on a trajectory/field?
I have seen that not every function $q(t)$ has a corresponding $\mathcal{L}$ such that $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial q}=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{q}}$, and I am assuming the same applies for fields. I am wondering, then, what properties a given function or field is guaranteed to have if it does have a corresponding Lagrangian. Given how generally the principle of least action is applied, I am assuming it enforces constraints that are somewhat physically intuitive. I have seen online that it requires "stability under perturbations"--I didn't find much of an elaboration but by the sound of it it requires that $\mathcal{L}+\delta\mathcal{L}$ has minimal action with the path $q+\delta q$ (or field $\phi+\delta \phi$), so perturbations are of similar order. I am wondering if anything else that is intuitive/motivating for the principle of least action can be said.

Hint: Given trajectory $t\mapsto q_0(t)$ define Lagrangian $L:=(q(t)-q_0(t))^2$.

In classical physics, you might propose many trajectories from initial to final conditions. Stationary action picks out the trajectory where $F=ma$ holds at every point.

A while ago I went back to the first question here on physics stackexchange on this subject and I posted a discussion of Hamilton's stationary action. Outline of motivation: we have that the true trajectory has the property that the rate of change of kinetic energy matches the rate of change of potential energy. In the case of Hamilton's stationary action: at the point in variation space such that the derivative of the kinetic energy matches the derivative of the potential energy the derivative of Hamilton's action is zero.
